# Pros and Cons of Buying Common Website Mispellings

Tags: domains, domain-registration, multiple-domains, top-level-domains

I own a website that is nicely short but somewhat easy to misspell.  I would like to buy the three or four most common mispellings and redirect them all to my main page.  Are there any major problems with this?

I could see it being considered duplicate content and it could make visitors confused as to what the actual name is.  Is there anyway to migitate these and other problems?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a 301 redirect on each of these misspelled sites it does not cause a problem with duplicate content.  For all intents and purposes, there is only 1 website when you 301 redirect the other sites to your main site.  [Here is a google forum question on the topic](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/94vsreHzYp4)

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please mark it as the chosen answer so that you and i can both get credit.

Comment: I think that you only answered one aspect of clifgray's question. Any input on visitors being confused on the name? Seems opinionated, but experience is experience.

Comment: @Christopher, I guess people might get confused but if he made a big deal out of the correct spelling at the top that might mitigate any confusion (and ppl might look back up at the url to see that they've been redirected to the correctly spelled website?)

Comment: yes I suppose you are right. I would imagine that they would notice the changed url and if they go to copy it then it will be the correct one.

Comment: I think even if they don't notice the changed URL, if your logo is clear, it should help mitigate any brand confusion, etc